# Retrieve text from image column in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012, typeconverter

In some third party application we are using, attached files are stored in database in columns declared as `image`.

I'm trying to convert the content to plain text.

I made a test putting string 'abc' into such a column; the `select` returns:

```
0x1F8C0200030000004B4C4A0600C2412435
```

I could not find a way to convert it back to string 'abc'

```
convert(nvarchar(max), Convert(varbinary(max)
```

won't help

I think this string 
0x1F8C0200030000004B4C4A0600C2412435
is used to recreate a file but how ?

1F 8C 02 00 means: UTF-32LE Encoding

03 00 00 00: number of characters in file

the rest is ambiguous and may be zipped

Comment: Well the obvious question is, what is actually in there? An xml document for instance would work, though it could be bigger than varchar max, so would get truncated, a jpg or some such, not going to be text ever. An other possibility is it's been compressed in someway.

Comment: actually string 'abc' in there 
it's stored as '0x1F8C0200030000004B4C4A0600C2412435'

Comment: Sudden thought try nvarchar(max), unicode...

Answer (score 0):

the only way to extract data in attachments is to use BMC API
https://rrr.se/cgi/index?pg=arapi